# Json schema validation using Wso2 ESB 4.8.1 and jackson-coreutils

Tags: json, jsonschema, wso2-esb

Is there a sample on how to use the jackson-coreutils for schema validation in Wso2 ESB version 4.8.1

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: For Json Schema Valiadtion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't do JSON schema validation in WSO2 ESB 4.8.1. You can validate your xml payload against xsd schema using validate mediator. There's no support to validate JSON payload against a JSON schema in WSO2 ESB. You may write a custom class mediator to do it by your own since there's no out of the box support at the moment. Class mediator is the only way you can add a custom extension to the ESB. Hope this helps.